# Protobuff identifiers performance

Tags: protobuf-net

In the protobuf-net documentation it states that identifiers on properties:

> lower numbers take less space - don't start at 100,000,000

Why is this, and are there are any other performance issues with using larger numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Field headers are encoded as varints; this aspect is because of how ["varint encoding"](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding#varints) works. Kinda similar to UTF-8, where we anticipate that `"abc"` (3 characters) takes 3 bytes, but `"Åℬℂ"` (also 3 characters) takes 9 bytes.

Essentially, "varint" is a 7-bit encoding where the 8th bit indicates continuation; 100,000,000 is (in binary) 101111101011110000100000000 - 27 bits; note that the "wire type" is also 3 bits on top of this, so in total we're looking at 30 bits, which means that with a 7-bit-plus-continuation encoding it will take 5 bytes (4×7=28 which is too small; 5×7=35).

As for other issues: there's also a reserved range that protobuf-net **does not enforce**, but which should be avoided: 19000 through 19999

Not directly related to field numbers, but general protobuf guidance: avoid negative varint number values unless you're using "zig-zag" encoding (`DataFormat.Signed` in protobuf-net terms).